# Solving the recurrence relation $y_{n+1}=y_n+a+\frac{b}{y_n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, recursion, nonlinear-dynamics

I am hoping to obtain a closed-form solution or an asymptotic result for the recurrence relation

$$y_{n+1}=y_n+a+\frac{b}{y_n}$$

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any indication that such a closed form exists, or just hoping?

Comment: I have no indication that a closed-form expression is possible, but an asymptotic result in the limit of large n seems likely. A plot seems to suggest that the difference y[n+1]-y[n] decays hyperbolically in n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that
$a, b, y_0$
are all positive.

From
$y_{n+1}
=y_n+a+\frac{b}{y_n+a}
$
it follows that
$y_{n+1}-y_n
=a+\frac{b}{y_n+a}
$
so that
$y_n
\gt na+y_0
$.
Therefore
$y_{n+1}-y_n
\lt a+\frac{b}{(n+1)a+y_0}
$.

Summing,
$y_{n}-y_0
\lt na+b\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{(n+1)a+y_0}
\lt na+\frac{b}{a}(\ln(n)+c)
$
so
$y_n
\lt na+\frac{b}{a}\ln(n)+d
$
where $d$ is a computable constant.

From this lower bound,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
y_{n+1}-y_n
&\gt a+\frac{b}{na+\frac{b}{a}\ln(n)+d+a}\\
&= a+\frac{b}{(n+1)a+(b/a)\ln(n)+d}\\
&= a+\frac{b}{(n+1)a}\frac1{1+\frac{(b/a)\ln(n)+d}{(n+1)a}}\\
&= a+\frac{b}{(n+1)a}\frac1{1+\frac{b\ln(n)+da}{(n+1)a^2}}\\
&> a+\frac{b}{(n+1)a}(1-\frac{b\ln(n)+da}{(n+1)a^2})
\quad\text{since }\frac1{1+x} > 1-x\\
&= a+\frac{b}{(n+1)a}-\frac{b(b\ln(n)+da)}{(n+1)^2a^3}\\
\end{array}
$

Since 
$\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$
converges,
summing this gives
$y_n
\gt na+\frac{b}{a}\ln(n) + C$
for come constant $C$.

More effort might yield
$\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n- na-\frac{b}{a}\ln(n)
$
existing
(and it probably does),
but I'll stop here.

Note:
This is a fairly standard
upper-lower bound technique
for getting asymptotics.

Comment: Thank you so much for this nice write-up. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Set $y_n = P_n(y,1)/Q_n(y,1)$ with:
$$P_0(y,z) = y,\quad Q_0(y,z) = z.$$
Then
$$
P_{n+1}(y,z) = {P_n(y,z)}^2 + a P_n(y,z)Q_n(y,z) + b {Q_n(y,z)}^2,\\
Q_{n+1}(y,z) = P_n(y,z)Q_n(y,z)
$$
provides a generalization of, and replacement for, the original recurrence relation. Note the property:
$$P_{n+k}(y,z) = P_k\left(P_n(y,z),Q_n(y,z)\right), \quad Q_{n+k} = Q_k\left(P_n(y,z),Q_n(y,z)\right),$$
and also:
$$Q_n(y,z) =  P_{n-1}(y,z) ⋯ P_1(y,z) P_0(y,z) z\quad (n>0).$$
Thus,
$$y_n = \frac{P_n(y,1)}{P_{n-1}(y,1) ⋯ P_1(y,1) P_0(y,1)}\quad (n>0).$$

These are all homogeneous polynomials of degrees $\text{deg}(P_n) = 2^n = \text{deg}(Q_n)$. The lowest orders are:
$$
P_0(y,z) = y,\\
P_1(y,z) = y^2 + ayz + bz^2,\\
P_2(y,z) = y^4 + 3ay^3z + \left(2a^2+3b\right)y^2z^2 + 3abyz^3 + b^2z^4.
$$
and
$$
Q_0(y,z) = z,\\
Q_1(y,z) = yz,\\
Q_2(y,z) = (y^2 + ayz + bz^2)yz.
$$

Note also the properties
$$P_n(ky,kz) = k^{2^n} P_n(y,z), \quad Q_n(ky,kz) = k^{2^n} Q_n(y,z),$$
follow from homogeneity so that
$$P_n(y,z) = z^{2^n} P_n\left(\frac{y}{z},1\right), \quad Q_n(y,z) = z^{2^n} Q_n\left(\frac{y}{z},1\right)\quad (z ≠ 0),$$
while
$$P_n(y,0) = y^{2^n},\quad Q_n(y,0) = 0.$$

For the rational function, there is the following normalization
$$\frac{P_n(y,z)}{Q_n(y,z)} = \frac{P_n(y/z,1)}{Q_n(y/z,1)}\quad (z ≠ 0),$$
and the following reduction to a polynomial + proper rational function:
$$\frac{P_n(y,1)}{Q_n(y,1)} = y + na + b\frac{R_n(y,1)}{Q_n(y,1)},\quad \text{deg}_y\left(R_n(y,1)\right) < \text{deg}_y\left(Q_n(y,1)\right).$$
This can be expanded as a series in $1/y$:
$$\frac{P_n(y,1)}{Q_n(y,1)} = y + na - \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{ab}{y} + \frac{n(n-1)}{6}\frac{ab}{y}\frac{(2n-1)a+(n-2)b}{y} + ⋯.$$
You can cut the series off at any finite order by writing the remainder term in the form ${R_n}'(y,1)/Q_n(y,1)$ for a suitably-defined polynomial ${R_n}'(y,z)$.

There is no magic that I can see that will reduce this to anything simpler. You'll just have to take these primitives as things in their own right, and make a whole new subject out of them.